# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I  have  some problems . There  is  a code

```
function doGoogleLanguageTranslator(a) {
    if (a.value) a = a.value;
    if (a == '') return;
    var b = a.split('|')[1];
    var c;
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
        if (d[i].className == 'goog-te-combo') c = d[i];

    if (typeof(c) !== 'undefined') {

        if (document.getElementById('google_language_translator') == null || document.getElementById('google_language_translator').innerHTML.length == 0 || c.length == 0 || c.innerHTML.length == 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                doGoogleLanguageTranslator(a)
            }, 500)
        } else {
            c.value = b;
            GLTFireEvent(c, 'change');
            GLTFireEvent(c, 'change')
        }


    }  else {
        if (document.getElementById('google_language_translator') == null || document.getElementById('google_language_translator').innerHTML.length == 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                doGoogleLanguageTranslator(a)
            }, 500)
        } else {
           var  c ;
            c.value = b;
            GLTFireEvent(c, 'change');
            GLTFireEvent(c, 'change')
        }
    }
 }
```

I  have  errors . Program  don't  understand  declarated  c .             c.value = b;   - this  is  error

Comment: Please , help me  to  solve  that  problem

Comment: declaration  code ` function GLTFireEvent(a, b) {
    try {
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var c = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            c.initEvent(b, true, true);
            a.dispatchEvent(c)
        } else {
            var c = document.createEventObject();
            a.fireEvent('on' + b, c)
        }
    } catch (e) {}
}

Comment: Please, help us help you. Include all the required code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might lie here:

```
    else {
   var  c ;
    c.value = b;
    GLTFireEvent(c, 'change');
    GLTFireEvent(c, 'change')
}
```

You have declared c as a simple variable. Instead declare c as an object:

```
   var c = {} ;
```

Comment: This will give error, as he already declared the var at top, and checks if it undefined (this check will not be right because c will be object and not undefined)

Comment: I was referring to the last else block, which will be executed only if c is undefined. There, the problem is initializing c as a variable and then trying to access attribute 'value'

Answer (score 0):

```
} else {
    c = { value: b };
    GLTFireEvent(c, 'change');
    GLTFireEvent(c, 'change')
}
```

This should work, c is undefined, and you can't set properties to undefined types.

when you do `var c;` you just put it as undefined, `var c = {}` set c to empty object, with empty object you can set properties.